# Form validation with entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I got an entity class "user" with a corresponding database table, which contains many fields (id, email, firstname, lastname, encryptedPassword, enabled, role).
However if the admin wants to add a new user on the web application, he only has to fill in certain fields in the form (firstname, lastname, email). The rest of the fields are filled by a UserService.

When trying to validate the form input with BindingResult in the controller class, BindingResult contains errors, that id, encryptedPassword, enabled and role must not be null. So my question is: What is the most fashionable way to achieve a working form validation without too much code duplication?

UserEnitity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 60)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "e_mail", unique = true)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Size(max = 60)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 60)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Size(max = 120)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "encrypted_password")
    private String encryptedPassword;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Boolean enabled;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private Role role;
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("employees")
public class EmployeesController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeesController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String getAddEmployeesPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "employees/add";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String postAddEmployeesPage(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "employees/add";
        }

        userService.addUser(user);

        return "redirect:/employees/add/?successful=true";
    }
}
```

Form:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/employees/add}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label th:text="#{employees.add.first_name}" for="first_name"></label>
                    <input th:placeholder="#{employees.add.first_name}" th:field="*{firstName}" type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label th:text="#{employees.add.last_name}" for="last_name"></label>
                    <input th:placeholder="#{employees.add.last_name}" th:field="*{lastName}" type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name">
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label th:text="#{employees.add.email}" for="email"></label>
                    <input th:placeholder="#{employees.add.email}" th:field="*{email}" type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></p>
                </div>
                <p><button th:text="#{button.submit}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button><button th:text="#{button.reset}" type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary"></button></p>
            </form>
```

Comment: You should probably be using DTOs, but what you're looking for is *validation groups*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("employees")
public class EmployeesController {

  private UserService userService;
  private Validator validator;

  @Autowired
  public EmployeesController(UserService userService, Validator validator) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

  @GetMapping("/add")
  public String getAddEmployeesPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "employees/add";
    }

  @PostMapping("/add")
  public String postAddEmployeesPage(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "employees/add";
        }
        if(!validateUserForm(user)){
          return "some error message";
        }
        userService.addUser(user);

        return "redirect:/employees/add/?successful=true";
    }

  private boolean validateUserForm(User user){

     Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
     if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
       for (ConstraintViolation<User> violation : violations) {
        // log violation.getMessage();
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
    }
```

Added a private method to the controller which you can call to validate your object against the constraints you have on your entity bean. I would recommend to move this validation to service layer.